# Running out of memory with DelayQueue

Tags: java, queue, executorservice

I've been trying to identify if this section of code is the cause of an application running out of memory, as is proposed by a MAT report.

> One instance of java.util.concurrent.DelayQueue loaded by  occupies 10,866,002,360 (22.41%) bytes.

in summary the code snippet is

```
private final ExecutorService timerExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(timerThreadFactory);
private final ExecutorService responseHandlerExecutor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool(responseHandlerThreadFactory);

timerExecutor.execute(() -> {
                while (true) {
                    try {
                        ResponseCallback responseCb = delayQueue.take();
                        if (!responseCb.isProcessed()) {
                            LOG.warn("RPC request with id {} timedout ", responseCb.getRpcId());
                            responseHandlerExecutor.execute(() -> responseCb.sendResponse(null));
                        }
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        LOG.info("interrupted while waiting for an element from delayQueue", e);
                        break;
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        LOG.warn("error while sending response from timeout handler", e);
                    }
                }
            });
```

Another report from a profiler mentions  that most memory allocation where made by one thread from responseHandlerExecutor

To me this doesn't look obvious. Not sure if someone could give me some insight.

Comment: Your elements are not expiring (we have no way to check from your code snippet) or you are processing them slower than they are being added (...). Possibly both.

Comment: Add a bit of logging after the `take` and see if anything expires at all.